# How to configure Visual Studio 2015 to develop device driver application(KMDF)?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, driver, device-driver, kmdf

I am newbie to device driver development and trying to configure `Visual Studio 2015` to develop `KMDF` project on my `windows 7`, I have installed `Visual Studio 2015, Windows Driver Kit(WDK)10` and `SDK10` too.
In Visual Studio when i create a `WDF->KMDF` project, project is not able find `"device.tmh"` file and other object like `NTSTATUS`, it seems that project is searching for KMDF library or header file.

After installation of `WDK10` and `SDK10` it create "windows kits" folder along with "8.0, 8.1 and 10" folder inside it.

Please let me know where i goes wrong or how to set library path to remove all error.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Install Visual Studio 2015.

2) Install Visual C++ (Not installed by default).

3) Install SDK10 (Not installed by default).

4) Install WDK10 (Not install by default).

There all setup is working fine for me.